# Persistent storage solution for Docker on AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy a node-red server on my AWS EC2 cluster. I got the docker image up and running without problems. Node-red stores the user flows in a folder named /data. Now when the container is destroyed the data is lost. I have red about several solutions where you can mount a local folder into a volume. **What is a good way to deal with persistent data in AWS EC2?**

My initial thoughts are to use a S3 volume or mount a volume in the task definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to use a [volume driver plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/) with docker that supports mapping EBS volumes.

[Flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/) was one of the first volume managers, it supports EBS and has evolved to support a lot of different back ends.

[Cloudstor](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/persistent-data-volumes/) is Dockers volume plugin (It comes with [Docker for AWS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/)/Azure).

[Blocker](https://github.com/joeduffy/blocker) is an EBS only volume driver.

S3 doesn't work well for all file system operations as you can't update a section of an object, so updating 1 byte of a file means you have to write the entire object again. It's also not immediately consistent so a write then read might give you odd/old results.

Comment: I'm trying to test Cloudstor but i cannot install it on my local machine. 
I use:
"docker plugin install cloudstor".
and the result is:
"Error response from daemon: pull access denied for cloudstor, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'".

So i tried login with aws and rerun the cmd but with same result. 
How do i install it?

Comment: Have you tried installing [Docker for AWS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/)?

Answer (score 1):

The EBS volume can only be attached to one instance which means that you can only run your docker containers in one EC2 instance. Assuming that you would like to scale your solution in future with many containers running in ECS cluster then you need to look into EFS. It’s a shared system from AWS. The only issue is performance degradation of EFS over EBS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and the most common approach) is run your docker with **-v /path/to/host_folder:/path/to/container_folder** option, so the container will refer to host folder and information will stay after it will be restarted or recreated. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) the detailed information about docker volume system.

Answer (score 0):

I would use AWS EFS. It is like a NAS in that you can have it mounted to multiple instances at the same time.

If you are using ECS for your docker host the following guide may be helpful http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_efs.html